# Watchify - следить и билдить все изменения в папке

Tags: npm

Есть npm скрипт

```
"watch": "watchify src/app.js -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] -v"
```

Таким образом я могу поставить вотчера за одним файлом.Как изменить скрипт так,чтобы watchify следил и билдил все файлы в указанной папке и выводил в другую папку?

Comment: для чего вам все файлы билдить? идея такая что `src/app.js` - это точка входа в приложение , вы туда подключаете нужные модули *import React from 'react';
import myModal from './components/myModal';* а скрипт заходит в `app.js` ищет зависимости и добавляет их в `bundle.js`

Comment: Да,я уже в процессе экспериментов догадался об этом,оказывается не нужно все преобразовывать,а просто преобразовывать главный файл,импортируя в него компоненты.Поставлю вам плюс.

Comment: спасибо! оформлю ответ чтобы вы смогли закрыть вопрос, если разобрались.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея такая, что `src/app.js` - *точка входа* в приложение. Вы туда подключаете нужные модули, например так:

```
import React from 'react';

import myModal from './components/myModal';
```

а скрипт заходит в `app.js` ищет зависимости и добавляет все их в `bundle.js`. Поэтому вам достаточно "следить" только за одним файлом - `app.js`